# What's the right way to optionally require a field using Flask-WTForms?

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I'm using Flask with Flask-WTForms and am writing an admin page where it's possible to update values for a user - including the password.

I'm using the same form page that I use for registration, but since it's not requisite that the password be updated, I don't want to require it. What is the right way to do this with Flask-WTForms?

I've got my `UserForm` in `forms.py` and I was thinking of making a custom validator and have a file-level `require_password` option that would override the default check. I'm fairly new to WTForms, and somewhat new to Flask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solution seems to do what I want:

In `forms.py`,

```
from flask.ext.wtf import Optional

def make_optional(field):
    field.validators.insert(0, Optional())

#Rest of code here...
```

Then inside my flask endpoint I can call:

```
user_form = UserForm()
forms.make_optional(user_form.password)
if user_form.validate_on_submit():
    #Go on your merry way!
```

---

That seems to do what I wanted - keep all the other validation (e.g. confirmation), while ignoring anything if there is no password present.

Comment: I am getting "ImportError: No module named flask.ext.wtf.Optional"

Comment: @vivi You could try "from wtforms.validators import Optional" to see if it would work for you.